# Accidentaly created a different user when reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs, username

I had set my computer to dual boot Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8. I tried upgrading to 15.10, but the auto-upgrade just hung.

I then installed Ubuntu 15.10 to my Ubuntu partition. In doing so, I created a new user account.

I was able to successfully install 15.10, and I can still go back and forth between Ubuntu and Windows 8 at start-up. However, when I log into my user account for Ubuntu, I'm greeted with an empty home directory.

In my /home directory, I see `newuser` and `olduser`.

In `olduser`, I see:

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  .ecryptfs  .Private  README.txt
```

I hope that `olduser` contains all of my documents, files, etc.

I've been struggling to decrypt `olduser` using `ecryptfs-utils`. But, more importantly, I want to set `olduser` to be my default home directory, and go back to using my old user login.

How do I switch away from `newuser` to `olduser` such that, when I start-up and log in, `olduser` will be my default home directory as it was before the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I would first backup all the important data you want to keep, including the currently encrypted files in your olduser home. Does `ecryptfs-recover-private` not work to decrypt your old home files? It should, if you remember the old login passphrase, or you have the mount passphrase.

I don't think renaming the olduser home to something else is needed, the next step should just use the existing folder as the home for the "new olduser".

Then create a new user with your desired name, probably "olduser"? Use the *same* login passphrase from before, then it will hopefully decrypt the home successfully when you login. Using the gui tools might have an option or checkbox to encrypt the user's home, I think it just runs `ecryptfs-migrate-home` on the new user, so I don't think you want that. Or just use `adduser` in a terminal. This should use the existing home files in olduser.

Then if the olduser files aren't still in the olduser home, copy them back from the backup.

Then try logging in as "olduser". Hopefully it will decrypt the home (using the same login passphrase from before the reinstall) and work ok.

If it doesn't work, then renaming your old home, creating a new user "olduser" with the encrypted home checkbox, or using `ecryptfs-migrate-home` and then logging in as newuser and copy back the old home files from your backup should work.